# Asp.net Mvc- Check box always give unchecked on postback if disabled=true

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a check box and on post it always shows false (unchecked) state -:

Here is the simple code -:

```
 public ActionResult Index3()
        {
            var checkBoxTest = new CheckBoxTest() {Istrue = true};
            return View(checkBoxTest);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index3(CheckBoxTest checkBoxTest)
        {

            return View(checkBoxTest);
        }
```

Model -:

```
public class CheckBoxTest
{
    public bool Istrue { get; set; }
}
```

View -:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        Check Box Test:
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.Istrue,new{@disabled="disabled"})    
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>

}
```

Whenever I post it on server, checkbox always shows unselected state-

But if I remove -"new{@disabled="disabled"})" from attributes it works fine.

Most of the people I saw on internet have used the same technique for disabling check box - how in their case , it is working ? or may be I am making any mistake ...

Comment: That's just the html standard, disabled input elements are not submitted. Do you really need a disabled checkbox? Is it enough with a readonly checkbox?

Comment: Thanks . Good to know that disabled input elements are not submitted. So much to learn. Readonly perhaps does not work with checkboxes ? for the time being I have added new {onclick="return false"} ;) . Thanks a lot for the info .

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to submit the value back to server in this case, you can add a hidden variable like this:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Istrue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simon Svensson's comment is correct and Ankit Vijay's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25324133/2615878) provides a good work-around.

Another work-around, if you don't care that disabled check box is not submitted, is to add two lines to your `HttpPost ActionResult` as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index3(CheckBoxTest checkBoxTest)
{
    ModelState.Remove("Istrue");
    checkBoxTest.Istrue = true;
    return View(checkBoxTest);
}
```

Even though the checkbox won't be checked during the post, it will be checked when the form is redisplayed.

See [Rick Strahl's Web Log](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Apr/20/ASPNET-MVC-Postbacks-and-HtmlHelper-Controls-ignoring-Model-Changes) for a thorough explanation of why the `ModelState.Remove` line is needed.